# Stack level too deep: creating child-record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem: User has_one Profile. When new User is created, APP also automatically creates Profile, which belongs to User. I tried to do it through controller, through callback, always same error (Stack level too deep). My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
  validates :email, :email_format => true
  validates :password, :length=> {:in=> 5...32}
  validates :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :presence =>true
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :tests
  has_many :answers
  has_many :results
  has_one :profile
  #after_create :build_profile
  #tried this way

  def build_profile
    self.build_profile
  end

end
```

#

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :user_id
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

#

```
  def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        @user.email=@user.email.downcase
        if @user.save
          session[:user_id] = @user.id
          @profile=@user.build_profile
          redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
        else
         render "new"
        end
      end
```

Alsways same error. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def build_profile
  self.build_profile
end
```

This loops endlessly (and I can't see the point, what did you want to do?)

you should simply remove the `build_profile` method (don't worry, it's defined thanks to the association).

---

```
user = User.new

user.build_profile
  |_ calls self.build_profile, but self is user
    |_ calls user.build_profile
      |_ ...
```

Comment: Why endessly? user created=> after create callback=> user.build_profile. I want every User to have profile, so when user created, app should also create related profile

Comment: thanks) seems like my understading of how self works wasn't complete